# How to reade € char in java unicode

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, apache-camel

I'm reading file using java. File contains € chars but java interpret it like `¿.`

i.e. file content "`12rl+€/h`" reading from java "`12rl+¿/h`"

UPDATE: 
I'm reading it with using camel file component:

```
<camel:route id="FileProcessor">
  <camel:from uri="file:c://my/temp/" />
  <camel:log message="File ${body}" loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="CamelLogger"/>
  <camel:process ref="fileProcessor"/>
  <camel:log message="File has been processed" loggingLevel="DEBUG" logName="CamelLogger"/>
</camel:route>

public class FileProcessor implements Processor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileProcessor.class);

    public FileProcessor() {
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String fileContent = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        //Buisness logic with file
    }
```

How to fix this

Comment: How are you reading the value?

Comment: How do you read it? And how do you print out what you believe is read? (I.e., how have you confirmed that it reads the symbol wrongly?)

Comment: You need to set the encoding to match that of your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Camel, but Google lead me to this [documentation page](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html), which explains that an option can be added to the URL to specify the charset:

```
file:c://my/temp/?charset=UTF-8
```